# SQL does replace and CAST on select affect the Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am creating a view and I was asked to do a 'replace' and a 'cast', so as an example:

```
SELECT CAST(qtyshipped AS INT) AS 'QTYShipped', REPLACE(itemval,'.','')
FROM Database
```

Within the view, should not actually change the information in the database but just in the query correct? (It works perfectly in my sandbox server but i just want to confirm)

Comment: You will be fine.  In the future please include what type of database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Not a dumb question at all. And the answer is yes, it only changes the result of the query, the underlying data will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

That is already a good query. But I need to tell some points with you.

- REPLACE function is case-sensitive. Although I've seen in your code that you are only replacing period.
- Why is your column `qtyshipped` is not in numeric type? You should have change that into numeric. So you won't need casting which may *lower* the performance.

It will not affect your database since your are only executing `SELECT` not `UPDATE`.

Comment: The database cannot be changed (SAGE 300) so I have to make due with what is given. Thank you for your time!

Comment: `REPLACE` is only case sensitive if on a CS collation. Most installs aren't.